# How to copy the graphics of a movieclip to another movieclip(adobe flash cs5)

Tags: actionscript, flash-cs5

If I duplicate the movieclip then make some changes to it, the previous movieclip is affected to, how can i edit 2 movieclips without affecting each other? in adobe flash without code actionscript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is probably happening is that you have another MovieClip or symbol inside that is shared by both clips. So when you edit that symbol it gets updated in both MovieClips.

You can either create a duplicate of the sub-clip and replace it in one of the MovieClips (so they contain different symbols), or you can break it apart (if you don't need it to be a symbol). Then changes you make to one clip won't affect the other.